# Using a javascript variable inside C# block

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

i am trying to get a variable by javascript and using it in my C# block but it looks like impossible.

this is my HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="Category">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Categori)
    {
        <option value="@item.CategoriId">@item.CategoriName</option>
    }
</select>
<div id="Container"></div>
```

and this is my javascript code:

```
$('#Category').on('change', function (e) {
   $("#Container").append(`@foreach (var item in Model.YetkinlikKategorileri.Where(x => x.Id == $('#Category').val()))
   {
       <p>hello</p>
   }`);
});
```

well is it possible to do something like that ? if not is there another way ?

Comment: you must create a js array and in foreach put all data to that array. then append array instead of this code

Comment: Javascript is ran on the client. All your c# code will be compiled on page load. That's why it doesn't only look impossible but in fact it is impossible for it to execute like this.

Comment: *"if not is there another way ? "* yes, ajax. Make a request and ask the server to give you the categories for a provided ID as json. then process the json and add the nodes/markup to the `#Container`.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  At the moment it pseudo looks like you want to put "hello" into a div when the value of a dropdown changes, but you're also trying to identify an item in a collection, by the value of the dropdown.

Comment: not possible, because when you pass model data from controller to view, first data will apply extract and then page will load to your browser, so if you wan to use try with ajax

Comment: Guys - he can do it without Ajax.  It's not clear what he's trying to do though, so without further info you're just confusing an already confusing issue.

Comment: thanks all for answers. what i am trying to do is not to push hello ofcourse but my code is kind of complicated so i just tried to simplize it . the user will choose a category and i have to show the products of that categori. thats what i am trying to .

Comment: I hope you won't write such code in real project. Imagine such mess in real big projects, and imagine yourself to figure out in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
<script> 
var data = [
        @foreach (var item in dataList)
        {
            @Html.Raw("'"+item+"',")
        }
    ];
    $('#Category').on('change', function (e) {
        var lst = data.find(/*Your condition*/);
        for (var i = 0; i < lst.length; i++) {
            $("#Content").append("<p>hello</p>" + data[i] + "<br/>");
        }
    };
</script>
```

`dataList` is the data which comes from server.

But in this way, you should get all data from server and put it into javascript `data` array. Then you should make `lst` by finding in `data` array.

But using ajax is better than this razor code.